# Отложить загрузку <script>

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

Есть достаточно массивная карта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Adb6daf7023d35dc56770ae50d551f5dee452afcabf206dcd9223a0167506d503&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=500&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

И она очень сильно замедляет загрузку страницы. Вопрос, есть ли способ отложить ее загрузку до полной загрузки DOM? Или любой другой способ прооптимизировать это дело.

Пунктов на карте несколько тысяч.

Comment: Так defer не работает же с инлайноавм js

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо заменить атрибут `async` на `defer` - данный атрибут откладывает загрузку скрипта до момента пока страница полностью не будет загружена.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Adb6daf7023d35dc56770ae50d551f5dee452afcabf206dcd9223a0167506d503&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=500&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

Так-же можно использовать искусственную задержку где `speed=0` определяет задержку загрузки:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Adb6daf7023d35dc56770ae50d551f5dee452afcabf206dcd9223a0167506d503&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=500&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true?speed=0"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно что то такое

```js
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout( function(){ сюда пишешь вызов своей карты }, 2000);
}
```

Или вызывать карту, только если пользователь доскролил до нужного участка страници

Comment: Спасибо большое, но нужно небольшое уточнение. Ваш способ мне нравится, но я не очень понимаю JS, помогите, как должен выглядеть конечный вариант? Свой код я просто вставляю в html и карта грузится. Сайт на простом конструкторе WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

засунь путь подключение в атрибут data-src, а после загрузки страницы и отложенного времени перенеси data-src в src и вуаля, скорость загрузки первого контента быстрее, а карта подключается позже.